# Can not delete file and folder in android 8 and above

Tags: android, file, erase

i can't delete file & folder in android 8 and above. file.delete() return false in all possible way

```
File csvFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Notes/help.csv");
File txtFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Notes/MyFile.txt");
folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Notes");

if (csvFile.exists()) csvFile.delete();
if (txtFile.exists()) txtFile.delete();
if (folder.exists()) folder.delete();
```

Comment: may be the file is in use of some other program

Comment: please add stacktrace

Comment: @Muhammad Muzammil Sharif no other program not accessing the file

Answer (score -1):

When you do `new File()` it doesn't create anything, it is just an object that points to a file (a bit like a path). If you were to write to that file object then it would exist, and then you could delete it.

In other words, I think you can't delete it because you never created it in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

This may be a permission problem.

Starting from Android 8, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE need to request separately. So even if you can read the file, it is possible you can't delete it.

If you are sure not a permission problem, then change your code to

```
try {
   Files.delete(theFileName);
} catch (Exception e) {
   log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
}
```

Which will give you the reason why delete failed.

Comment: i take both of then android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE separately

Comment: @neelanjan bhattacharya  have you tried Files.delete and does it give you the reason?